# Prevent Vim from clearing the terminal after exit

Tags: terminal, linux, quit

If I do:

```
$ less file
```

And press `q` to exit `less`, I stil see the same text as I had on the screen when `less` was still running.

However, if I do

```
$ vim file
```

And `:q`, my terminal is blanked...

Screenshots of my terminal after quiting `less` and `vim`:

[image]
[image]

Can I somehow prevent this? This is *only* on my Linux system. My FreeBSD system actually works as expected (using the same software/settings all around, `TERM` is `xterm-color` for both, `vim -u NONE` doesn't make a difference).

Example of what I would like to have:

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

By default VIM, when terminating, sends the string configured with the option `t_te` to the hosting terminal to tell it to clear the screen. To avoid it just `:set t_te=` to send nothing to the terminal and avoid screen clearing. See `:help term` form more information about terminal capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

As you are using an xterm you could use its main and alternate screen buffers for screen swapping, as in [this section from my .vimrc](https://github.com/jalanb/dotjab/blob/master/vim/vimrc#L263)

```
if &term == "linux"
    set t_ti=^[[?1049h
    set t_te=^[[?1049l
endif
```

Note: `^[` is *not* literal text, it is the escape character, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>Esc</kbd> to insert it.

These vim commands add the relevant commands which can be missing from the linux terminfo entry. More info at

```
:help xterm-screens
```

Comment: Hm, still doesn't seem to do anything? It works as if I use `set t_te=`, but it's supposed to do more, I think?